# Navigation Bar HTML+CSS

Tags: html, css, html-lists, nav

Basically I would like to change my navigation bar so that the first child will float to the left and the last  child to the right, leaving the 3 other list items in the center. I have a feeling that the answer lies somewhere between flex-box and creating a table! I'm unsure if there is a better way to do this.

HTML:

```
<nav role="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Random</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Account Summary</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Statements</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Payments & Transfers</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Random</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
  nav {
    width:100%;
}

nav ul{
    font-size: 1.4em;
    color: white;
    margin:auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding:30px;
    border-top: 1px solid #1C1B1A;
    background-color: rgb(63,67,120);
    /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(63,67,120,1) 0%, rgba(32,35,74,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(63,67,120,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(32,35,74,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(63,67,120,1) 0%,rgba(32,35,74,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(63,67,120,1) 0%,rgba(32,35,74,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(63,67,120,1) 0%,rgba(32,35,74,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(63,67,120,1) 0%,rgba(32,35,74,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3f4378', endColorstr='#20234a',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
}

nav ul li{
    width:100%;
    display: inline;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: auto;
}

nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
    padding:30px;

}

nav ul li a:hover {
    background: #20234B;
}`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
nav ul li:first-child a{
    float:left;
}  
nav ul li:last-child a{
    float:right;
```

}

If you want to keep the design:

```
nav ul li:first-child a{
    float:left;
   margin-top:-30px;
}  
nav ul li:last-child a{
    float: right;
  margin-top:-30px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, seemed I had it working last night minus the minus margin-top...
Why does it add the extra margin? :/

Comment: It does not. you have the PADDING TOP in the link<a> and not in the <li>, when you float the <li> you start from the padding position.